# First two events out of twenty which are distributed uniformly

Tags: uniform-distribution

This is not a homework question but something that occured to me while studying for an examination. Is there a "shortcut" way of calculating this?

> There are $20$ independent uniform random variables, each denoting an event, $X_i $ ~ $ U(0,1)$ for $1 \leq i \leq 20$ (uniform continuous). What is the average time until the second event takes place?

I said the following:

> $P(\text{first two events happen} \leq t) = P(X_1 \leq t)P(X_2 \leq t)P(X_3 \geq t) ... P(X_{20} \geq t) + P(X_1 \leq t)P(X_3 \leq t)P(X_2 \geq t)...P(X_{20} \geq t)...$

Meaning, it is equal to the following:
$ \left(\matrix{20 \\ 2}\right)t^2(1-t)^{18}$

But I get a negative number when trying to calculate the mean (average) of this (derive and calculate mean), so my approach is clearly wrong. What is the correct way of tackling this, and what is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding that $P(0 \le X_i <t)=t\; |\,0 \le t <1$, then

- We have a continuous random variable $X$, that can assume values in $[0,1)$ with uniform probability;
- we make $n=20$ indipendent tests, and record the outcomes of  them as the vector $(X_1, \, X_2, \, \cdots , \, X_n)$;
- the space of events $U$ is the $n$-dimensional hypercube of side $1$, with a uniform probability density;
- we want to know the probability of that portion of hypercube in which one component of the vector
  is in $[0,t)$, another is in $[t,t+dt)$ and all the remaining in $[t+dt,1)$;
- since the result of a test run is a vector, order is to be taken into account (we are dealing with equi-probable *n-tuples*, not with equi-probable *n-subsets*);
- I can choose one event, the first, in $n$ ways, to occur in $[0..t)$ with $P_1=t$
- another event, the second, in $n-1$ ways, to occur at $[t..t+dt)$, with $P_2=dt$
- all the remaining, in one way, to occur at $[t+dt..1)$, with $P=(1-t)^{n-2}+O(dt)$

thus the probability density is $p_2(t)=n(n-1)t(1-t)^{n-2}$, and the average will be
$$
\eqalign{
  & E(t_{\,2} ) = n\left( {n - 1} \right)\int_{t = 0}^1 {t^{\,2} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,n - 2} dt}  = 
n\left( {n - 1} \right){\rm B}(3,n - 1) = n\left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {{{2!\left( {n - 2} \right)!} \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{2!} \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)}} = {2 \over {21}} \cr} 
$$
where ${\rm B}(x,y)$ is the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Note that for $n=3$ we would get $ E(t_{\,2} ) =1/2$, which is to be expected for symmetry.

*Addendum*

Note that in case we were looking for the time of occurrence of the **third** event, then the probability density would be:
$$
p_{\,3} (t) = {{n\left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {n - 2} \right)} \over {2!}}t^{\,2} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,n - 3} 
$$

The division by $2!$ is due to that $t^2$ is the probability of the first two events to occur in *whichever order*
while $n(n-1)$ counts the ways that they occur *orderly* 
(and shall then be associated to a probability $\int_{\tau _{\,2}  = 0}^{\,t} {\tau _{\,2} \left( {\int_{\tau _{\,1}  = 0}^{\tau _{\,2} } {\tau _{\,1} d\tau _{\,1} } } \right)d\tau _{\,2} } $).

Thus in the **general case** (probability of $m$-th event occurring at $t$) we have:
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
p_{\,m} (t) = {{n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } } \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}t^{\,m - 1} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,n - m} 
 }$$
where $n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } $ denotes the *Falling Factorial*.

In fact
$$
\eqalign{
  & \int_{t = 0}^1 {p_{\,m} (t)dt}  = {{n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } } \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}\int_{t = 0}^1 {t^{\,m - 1} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,n - m} dt}  = 
{{n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } } \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}\;{\rm B}(m,n - m + 1) =   \cr 
  &  = {{n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } } \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}{{\left( {m - 1} \right)!\left( {n - m} \right)!} \over {n!}} = 1 \cr} 
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,m\, \le \,n} {p_{\,m} (t)}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,m\, \le \,n} {{{n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } } \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}t^{\,m - 1} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,n - m} }  =   \cr 
  &  = n\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,m\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  m - 1 \cr}  \right)t^{\,m - 1} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,\left( {n - 1} \right) - \left( {m - 1} \right)} }  = n \cr} 
$$
i.e. $P (\text{any event in}[t,t+dt))=n dt/T$ as should be.

*Note about your approach*

Your calculation is correct, as far as it returns the probability that
two events (whatever) occur **before  $t$** and the remaining **at or after $t$**.
Therefore it includes the cases $[t_{1},t_{1}+dt_{1})<[t_{2}+dt_{2}) < [t,1)$
integrated over $t_{1},t_{2}$, so it is somewhat of a **cumulative** probability.
But to the purpose of calculating $E(t_2)$ this cannot be used, because of two bugs:
 -  the value $t$ is assigned also to the case $t_2<t$;
 - the remaining events are taken to occur always after $t$, not after $t_2$ (so you cannot use the derivative of *your* probability).

Comment: I have a question regarding this. If $P_2 = dt$, why does it not appear in $p_2(t)$? Is it because it appears already in the integral?

Comment: Sorry for another comment, but for some reason I can not edit the above one. I can not help but notice that the answer is $1+$ my answer. Why is that? Why is my solution wrong/not complete?

Comment: @TheNotMe: $p$ is the probability **density** $=P/dt$, i.e., $P=pdt$

Comment: @TheNotMe: I widened my answer, adding some more explanations. Wish it is more clear now.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Comment: glad that it  is helpful

Comment: Was wondering, as one last question: why was what I did wrong?

Comment: @TheNotMe: added note about. Be warned in general that Probability is a sort of .. Sirens' island, so always tight yourself to the mast of probability's axioms!

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand.